# Eclipse OSGi launch configuration does not show my bundles

Tags: eclipse, debugging, osgi, bundles

I'm developing OSGi bundles on Felix, now I want to use also Maven and have therefore installed the Apache Felix maven-bundle-plugin. 
I am working with the example on 
http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/MavenFelixBundlePluginEclipseToolchain

Building with maven from the command line is ok. I could also import the project(s) into Eclipse. Now in the chapter "Launching and Debugging", I try to create the launch configuration as described. However, I cannot see my bundles. Beside the bundles under "Target Platform", there are no other bundles listed. How can I make my bundles visible to the list in the OSGI Framework run configuration? 
What I want is an easy way to test and debug the bundles from withing Eclipse, i.e. without having to move them to a separate OSGi installation etc. So that tutorial looks exactly like what I need.

I'm using Eclipse Juno, with Eclipse Plugin Development installed. 
Moving the project from some direcory into a subdirectory of the workspace did not help, nor did restarting Eclipse (as recommended in the tutorial). The bundles have no dependency on any part of Eclipse.

Answer (score -2):

Try to convert the projects to "plug-in" projects: from the context menu choose `Configure` -> `Convert to plug-in projects`.

Then you should see your bundles in the *Launch configuration*, under the *Workspace* group.